# Pass Team's Culture in Azure Bot Sign in link

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

The oauth at my backed expects a culture to render the login page in user's language. I have an oauth connection settings on my bot which works as expected. But now I want it also to include the culture from team.Like below:

https://oauthprovider/auth?&**culture=en-US**&response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fwww.myapp.com

How in Generic oauth V2 or in code, I can provide Team's language . I tried below code, but it does not work:

```
string signInLink = await GetSignInLinkAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            
signInLink = $"{signInLink}&culture={turnContext.Activity.GetLocale()}";
```

Any suggestions, will help me a lot!

Comment: Is it working if you are passing hardcoded culture in your code?

Comment: No. It returns a Bot url , that later on browser translate to oauth url of my bacnkend.

Comment: We are checking with engineering team if there is any way to pass Team's culture in Azure Bot Sign in link. We will inform you once we have any update. Thanks!

Comment: The Teams locale can be obtained from the turnContext.Activity.Entities collection. The locale is included in the msteams object within the Entities collection.

`string locale = string.Empty;
var msteams = turnContext.Activity.Entities?.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Type == "msteams");
if (msteams != null)
{
    locale = msteams.Properties["locale"]?.ToString();
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(locale))
{
    locale = "en-US"; // default value
}
string signInLink = await GetSignInLinkAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
signInLink = $"{signInLink}&culture={locale}";`